Trying to mock a bullMQ call with Jest in a nextJS/typescript app
I have attempted MANY iterations of trying to test this function with both auto-mocks and manual-mocks using Jest and I have been close but unable to succeed.
If anyone has any suggestions, please...  please...
async function queueWorkerJob(id: string, type: string, date: string) {
  const data = {
    id,
    type,
    date,
  };
  await queue.add('integration', data, jobQueueConfig);
  await queue.close();
}

export default queueWorkerJob;

